# client-server game secure architecture

Tags: iphone, security, client-server

I am currently designing a distributed iOs game. It must contains kind of an authentication (username, password pair I think but please give me other idea if you have). I plan to do it through a simple RESTful API coded in Perl.

I know it is kind of a classic problems. I've seen lots of posts on the web talking about how to do this securely. However, too much informations kill its informative goal. So, I am a bit lost. Nevertheless, I've tried to outpoint the basics concepts, namely:

- use SSL (so use https url), it allows you not to think about encryption
- use embedded private keys shared between the server and the client, but how to embed them is the question! It allows to use HMAC and to do kind of an authentication.
- forget about absolute security (because you use security by obscurity): if anyone can destroy your security by decompiling your app, you gonna have problems !

Here are the questions:

- how to share private keys ?
- what to send to the server ? username/password encrypted ? some api key ?
- do I have the right approach (securing a personal restful api) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's quite broad question. So it may get closed because of this.

Trying to break down your questions to sub-questions/sub-notes

1) First and most important, as you pointed out. There is no absolute security. You should defined what is valuable (what are you trying to protect) and against who are you trying to protect:

- unauthorized user
- unauthorized user with inner knowledge of your app (reverse engineered)
- authorized user with inner knowledge of your app (reverse engineered)

1) https is "the must". As you figured it out, you don't have to worry about privacy and integrity.

2) In most cases, an app should send username and *plain* password. This password should be hashed by the server (don't forget to add some salt to it) and compare to stored hashes in your DB.

3) I don't think that you need to share any private keys between client and servers for several reasons:

- SSL ensures privacy (so no one can eavesdrop)
- Encryption of any parameters using shared secret key which is hardcoded doesn't help too much (it could be reverse engineered and extracted from your app)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, I know my question is too broad. Sorry for that! And how do you suggest I send the username/password pair to the server: a simple GET request with SSL ? Or classic http digest auth ? Is there a security matter here ? And must I send the credentials with every requests or set kind of a ticket for the next requests.

Comment: I would say, it depends on your server side. Take a look what is available in your framework and use it (to not reinvent the bicycle). Quite common method is to issue long living secure cookie (generally speaking - a ticket), which is used in all following requests.